# Calculate and apply a new ProhibitSendQuota with Powershell

Tags: powershell, exchange-server-2007

With this command :

```
get-mailbox -identity JSMITH | select ProhibitSendQuota
```

i get the *ProhibitSendQuota* for my mailbox JSMITH

I want to add 50 MB to the *ProbitiSendQuota*  **with just one powershell command line**

I have to use this command

```
set-mailbox -identity JSMITH -ProhibitSendQuota MyNewQuota
```

So what is the command to get the actual *ProhibitSendQuota* and had it 50 Mb ?
I think it's something like this but I don't know the exact syntax

```
get-mailbox -identity JSMITH | set-mailbox -identity $_.name -ProbibitSendQuota {($_.ProbititSendQuota) * 50 * 1024}
```

Someone have a solution ?

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Get-Mailbox -Identity jsmith | foreach{ $_ | Set-Mailbox -ProhibitSendQuota ($_.ProhibitSendQuota+50mb)}
```

Comment: Thanks @Shay Levy ! It works fine ! You just forgot "(" behind "$_."

Comment: Thanks, I've added the missing parenthesis. Consider marking it as the answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: I have a other question. Finally, I want ton add 50 MB to the TotalItemSize.Value.ToMB, how can I do ? Because I get TotalItemSize.Value.ToMB from get-mailboxstatistics and not from get-mailbox !